# Good and clear photos of original Sanskrit Manuscript of Mahabharata in full

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, ramayana, resource, manuscripts

Are there any good photos ie easy to read and good lighting of the whole Mahabharata and Ramayana including the accused "interpolated" options? Please include a Manuscript with headers for each Parva.